# Finding an upper bound for this expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-functions

Given two non-negative numbers $a$ and $b$, I'm trying to found an upper bound for
$-\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{a+b}$

But I'd like the bound not to be dependable on any square roots and have only one term. Namely, I want something like $O(a+b)$. Anyone knows how to obtain such a bound?

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{a}
&=\left(\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{a}\right)\frac{\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{a}}\\
&=\frac{a+b-a}{\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{a}}\\
&=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{a}}\\
&\le\frac{b}{\sqrt{a+b}}\\
&\le\frac{b}{\sqrt{b}}\\
&=\sqrt{b}\\
&\le1+b.~\blacksquare
\end{align}$$